# Navigation component navigate inside a onActivityResult not working

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult, android-architecture-navigation

i am using
    navController.navigate(R.id.FragmentB)
to navigate from host fragment in MainActivity to navigate to different fragments and it works like expected except inside onActivityResult it won't respond ,i am returning an ID from other activity and want to navigate to Fragments depending on that ID but it is not responding ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that i needed to create a Coroutine and run my navigation function on it , i tried with :

```
  GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    navigate()
    }
```

and it works fine, obviously gotta need to optimise my coroutine ,but that was the main issue

Comment: Sounds like internally it's a `handler.post`.

Comment: can you explain more ?

Comment: By invoking a coroutine that would run in Main dispatcher, internally it invokes `Handler.post`, which means that onActivityResult -> onStart -> onResume runs before your code. If you do it directly in onActivityResult, then onStart hasn't run, the NavController says its state is restored, and it ignores your navigate call.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not using coroutines, a simple `Handler()` will do the trick.

```
Handler().post {
    navigate()
}
```